# How is it possible to connect two apache servers with the same domain name on debian?

Tags: apache, debian, haproxy

I would like to know if it is possible to connect two web servers on the same domain name, or if it is necessary to make sub-domains

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please edit and describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish. I do not recommend trying to run multiple Apache instances. Instead, configure multiple Virtual Hosts.

Comment: "connect two web servers" means nothing.  You mean that 2 servers handle the requests for 1 domain?  Yes, you need a load balancer in front to redirect the traffic to one or the other server.